# How to force Visual Studio Community Edition 2013 to save file using line endings Unix (LF)?

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio, unix, character-encoding

I need to force Visual Studio Community Edition 2013 to save file using line endings with Unix (LF).

I need this behavior for HTML/CSS/JS files.

I have read several related posts on SO, but I cannot find SAVE/ADVANCE OPTIONS in Visual Studio Community Edition.

Comment: Related https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409797.aspx options is missing in the COMMUNITY EDITION... any idea?

Comment: Possible solutions: http://www.grebulon.com/software/stripem.php